# Sitecore MongoDB not creating all database/collections

Tags: mongodb, sitecore

We are working on Sitecore deployment in Azure.

- Sitecore Experience Platform 8.0 rev. 160115
- MongoDB - 3.0.4

We installed MongoDB, and we can connect to localhost using Robomongo. We can only see “Analytics” database/collections.
Our connection strings setup are:

[Connectionstring.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpLHL.png)

But the other 3 databases and collections are not created.

- Tracking.live
- Tracking.history
- Tracking.contact

In Sitecore.Analytics.config file – the setting “Analytics.Enabled” is set to true.

[Sitecore.Analytics.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmzmA.png)

In log we found some references to xDB cloud initialization failed issues, therefore we disabled it.

Are we missing any configurations? Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that MongoDB is schemaless. Of course, in a production environment you would probably have to create these databases manually - to ensure that access rights are assigned correctly. But in a development environment, any database can be created on the fly.

The only reason the `analytics` database was created for you is because Sitecore creates indexes for the `Interactions` collection. Otherwise, you wouldn't see this database until xDB wrote some data into it. Same goes for any MongoDB collection - those won't appear until there's either data being written or an index created.

The other three databases will be created once the aggregation/processing logic is executed. I.e. when your instance starts to actually collect and process visit data.

As a conclusion, don't worry about these databases missing (for now). Just verify that xDB functionality is working properly.

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro Shevcheko we will monitor the environment and will verify xDB functionalities.